# Imágenes no aparecen en la página web

Tags: imagen, upload

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de 'Angular', tengo una sección con 4 cards para el perfil de los empleados y/o agentes. Lo que sucede es que las imágenes de cada persona no aparecen al momento de ver la página ya subida en la web.
1- He cambiado las rutas.
2- He utilizado otros formatos.
3- Utilice otras imágenes para los perfiles que son de prueba y sí funcionaron.
4- Las únicas que no funcionan son las que debo utilizar para el proyecto.

Agradezco la ayuda en cómo podría solucionar esto.

Comment: Como estás declarando la ruta de la imagen en la etiqueta img?

Comment: Las imágenes están en el componente.ts, la ruta es: profile1:string="assets/img/team/name1.jpg" y en el componente.html, en la etiqueta <img [src]="profile1">. El detalle es que la ruta no es el inconveniente, porque hice prueba con otras imágenes y si se logran ver en la página web. Parece que específicamente las 4 imágenes que corresponde a cada persona en el perfil no funcionan, pero no se a qué se debe.